# Watching for file changes when developing lambda docker image

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, aws-lambda

I have a TypeScript function defined at `src/index.ts` for AWS Lambda below. For the purpose of this question, it simply sends a JSON body with a "hello world" statement. While running the docker container locally and making a file change, the lambda return value should change accordingly.

```
import { Context, APIGatewayProxyResult, APIGatewayEvent } from "aws-lambda";

export const handler = async (
  event: APIGatewayEvent,
context: Context
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ text: "hello world" })
  };
};
```

My `yarn develop` command is equal to the following shell command:

```js
esbuild src/index.ts --watch --bundle --minify --sourcemap --platform=node --target=es2020 --outfile=build/index.js
```

Paired with `yarn develop`, I use the following `Dockerfile.dev` to set up my local development environment:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:16
RUN npm install --global yarn
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
# where transpiled index.js is pointed.
VOLUME /var/task/build
CMD [ "build/index.handler" ]
```

I use the following Makefile with a `develop` target to run my lambda locally.

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

APPNAME = hello-world

.PHONY: develop

develop:
    @docker build -f Dockerfile.dev -t $(APPNAME):dev .
    @docker run -p 9000:8080 -v $(shell pwd)/build:/var/task/build $(APPNAME):dev & yarn develop
```

Lastly, this is how I test my lambda output locally:

```bash
cfaruki@hello-world[main] curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}' | jq .
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   102  100   100  100     2    161      3 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   166
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": "{\"text\":\"hello world\"}"
}
```

With this context in mind, the issue I run into is what happens when I make a file change. If I change the response body to **anything else**, the file change is acknowledged in my terminal output. But the resultant output of my AWS lambda does not change.

```
docker run -p 9000:8080 -v /path/to/hello-world/build:/var/task/build hello-world:dev & yarn develop
yarn run v1.22.19
$ esbuild src/index.ts --watch --bundle --minify --sourcemap --platform=node --target=es2020 --outfile=build/index.js
01 Feb 2023 14:54:54,725 [INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/usr/app, handler=)
[watch] build finished, watching for changes...
01 Feb 2023 14:55:00,290 [INFO] (rapid) extensionsDisabledByLayer(/opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j) -> stat /opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j: no such file or directory
01 Feb 2023 14:55:00,290 [WARNING] (rapid) Cannot list external agents error=open /opt/extensions: no such file or directory
START RequestId: 5b738544-3713-4b41-86f8-7eca4355d230 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 5b738544-3713-4b41-86f8-7eca4355d230
REPORT RequestId: 5b738544-3713-4b41-86f8-7eca4355d230  Init Duration: 1.35 ms  Duration: 1143.56 ms    Billed Duration: 1144 ms    Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 3008 MB
[watch] build started (change: "src/index.ts") // <----- HERE IS THE CHANGE
[watch] build finished
```

I have validated that any change to my `src/index.ts` results in a change in `build/index.js`. I validate this by SSHing into the docker container and printing the file contents of `build/index.js`:

```bash
docker exec -it <CONTAINER-ID> /bin/bash
cat /var/task/build/index.js
```

It seems to me that the issue I am encountering is that the AWS Lambda docker image does not support live reloading of the function on file change. If that is the case, is there a way I can affect this behavior without adding another dependency to my development workflow?

Or is my only option to destroy and rebuild my docker image each time I make a file change? I am aware that `docker-compose` simplifies the process of rebuilding docker images. But I want to minimize the amount of configuration required by my project.

Comment: I think the problem is that esbuild doesn't implement HMR. So while it detects your change and rebuilds, it doesn't integrate with the browser. https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/464

Comment: HMR is a client-side JS concept. This AWS lambda runs in Node.js runtime. Hence why I'm testing with cURL :)